# How can I enable disabled radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

The following code works great in IE, but not in FF or Safari.  I can't for the life of me work out why.  The code is *supposed* to disable radio buttons if you select the "Disable 2 radio buttons" option.  It should enable the radio buttons if you select the "Enable both radio buttons" option.  These both work...

However, if you don't use your mouse to move between the 2 options ("Enable..." and "Disable...") then the radio buttons do not appear to be disabled or enabled correctly, until you click anywhere else on the page (not on the radio buttons themselves).

If anyone has time/is curious/feeling helpful, please paste the code below into an html page and load it up in a browser.  It works great in IE, but the problem manifests itself in FF (3 in my case) and Safari, all on Windows XP.

```js
function SetLocationOptions() {
  var frmTemp = document.frm;
  var selTemp = frmTemp.user;
  if (selTemp.selectedIndex >= 0) {
    var myOpt = selTemp.options[selTemp.selectedIndex];
    if (myOpt.attributes[0].nodeValue == '1') {
      frmTemp.transfer_to[0].disabled = true;
      frmTemp.transfer_to[1].disabled = true;
      frmTemp.transfer_to[2].checked = true;
    } else {
      frmTemp.transfer_to[0].disabled = false;
      frmTemp.transfer_to[1].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="frm" action="coopfunds_transfer_request.asp" method="post">
  <select name="user" onchange="javascript: SetLocationOptions()">
    <option value="" />Choose One
    <option value="58" user_is_tsm="0" />Enable both radio buttons
    <option value="157" user_is_tsm="1" />Disable 2 radio buttons
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <input type="radio" name="transfer_to" value="fund_amount1" />Premium&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="transfer_to" value="fund_amount2" />Other&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="transfer_to" value="both" CHECKED />Both
  <br /><br />
  <input type="button" class="buttonStyle" value="Submit Request" />
</form>
```

Comment: Umm, this is working in IE10 and FF: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6cAu/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get FF to mimic IE's behavior when using the keyboard, you can use the keyup event on the select box. In your example (I am not a fan of attaching event handlers this way, but that's another topic), it would be like this:

```
<select name="user" id="selUser" onchange="javascript:SetLocationOptions()" onkeyup="javascript:SetLocationOptions()">
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, IE has a somewhat non-standard object model; what you're doing shouldn't work but you're getting away with it because IE is being nice to you. In Firefox and Safari, document.frm in your code evaluates to undefined.

You need to be using id values on your form elements and use `document.getElementById('whatever')` to return a reference to them instead of referring to non-existent properties of the document object.

So this works a bit better and may do what you're after:

```
Line 27: <form name="frm" id="f" ...

Line 6: var frmTemp = document.getElementById('f');
```

But you might want to check out this excellent book if you want to learn more about the right way of going about things: [DOM Scripting](http://domscripting.com/book/) by Jeremy Keith

Also while we're on the subject, [Bulletproof Ajax](http://bulletproofajax.com/) by the same author is also deserving of a place on your bookshelf as is [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742) by Doug Crockford

Answer (score 1):

Why not grab one of the AJAX scripting libraries, they abstract away a lot of the cross browser DOM scripting black magic and make life a hell of a lot easier.